# Вывод URL параметров для получение конкретных данных

Tags: json, api

Есть к примеру вот такое апи, мне нужно сделать к апи я обращаюсь по ссылке http://localhost:3000/events мне нужно получить конкретные данные (тут для примера всего 3 ивента но будет конечно намного больше)
Я пытаюсь это сделать так(чтоб получить первый ивент):

```
http://localhost:3000/events?data[][id]=1
```

пробовал так

```
http://localhost:3000/events?data[0][id]=1

http://localhost:3000/events?data[0].id=1
```

не выходит вообще как правильно получать через get параметры нужные данные в апи по url?

```js
{
  "data": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "XI Московский марафон \"Самопревосхождение\"",
          "brief": "",
          "description": "<p>qwe qwe</p>",
          "type": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Run",
            "key": "run",
            "active": 1,
            "bookable": 1,
            "created_at": "2019-11-27 14:19:07",
            "updated_at": "2019-11-27 14:19:07"
          },
          "city": {
            "id": 1,
            "country_id": 1,
            "name": "Москва"
          },
          "country": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Россия"
          },
          "organization": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Nike running club",
            "type": "1",
            "email": "nrc@gmail.com",
            "description": "qwe qwe",
            "phone": "88002600",
            "website": "https://nrc.dev",
            "country_id": 1,
            "city_id": 1,
            "created_at": "2019-11-27 14:19:07",
            "updated_at": "2019-11-27 14:19:07"
          },
          "distances": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "name": "Марафон",
              "created_at": "2019-11-27 14:19:07",
              "updated_at": "2019-11-27 14:19:07",
              "pivot": {
                "event_id": 1,
                "distance_id": 1
              }
            },
            {
              "id": 2,
              "name": "Полумарафон",
              "created_at": "2019-11-27 14:19:07",
              "updated_at": "2019-11-27 14:19:07",
              "pivot": {
                "event_id": 1,
                "distance_id": 2
              }
            }
          ],
          "when": "2020-03-22",
          "start": "11:00:00",
          "active": 1,
          "bookable": 1
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "XI Московский марафон \"Самопревосхождение\"",
          "brief": "",
          "description": "<p>qwe qwe</p>",
          "type": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Run",
            "key": "run",
            "active": 1,
            "bookable": 1,
            "created_at": "2019-11-27 14:19:07",
            "updated_at": "2019-11-27 14:19:07"
          },
          "city": {
            "id": 1,
            "country_id": 1,
            "name": "Москва"
          },
          "country": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Россия"
          },
          "organization": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Nike running club",
            "type": "1",
            "email": "nrc@gmail.com",
            "description": "qwe qwe",
            "phone": "88002600",
            "website": "https://nrc.dev",
            "country_id": 1,
            "city_id": 1,
            "created_at": "2019-11-27 14:19:07",
            "updated_at": "2019-11-27 14:19:07"
          },
          "distances": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "name": "Марафон",
              "created_at": "2019-11-27 14:19:07",
              "updated_at": "2019-11-27 14:19:07",
              "pivot": {
                "event_id": 1,
                "distance_id": 1
              }
            },
            {
              "id": 2,
              "name": "Полумарафон",
              "created_at": "2019-11-27 14:19:07",
              "updated_at": "2019-11-27 14:19:07",
              "pivot": {
                "event_id": 1,
                "distance_id": 2
              }
            }
          ],
          "when": "2020-03-22",
          "start": "11:00:00",
          "active": 1,
          "bookable": 1
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "XI Московский марафон \"Самопревосхождение\"",
          "brief": "",
          "description": "<p>qwe qwe</p>",
          "type": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Run",
            "key": "run",
            "active": 1,
            "bookable": 1,
            "created_at": "2019-11-27 14:19:07",
            "updated_at": "2019-11-27 14:19:07"
          },
          "city": {
            "id": 1,
            "country_id": 1,
            "name": "Москва"
          },
          "country": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Россия"
          },
          "organization": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Nike running club",
            "type": "1",
            "email": "nrc@gmail.com",
            "description": "qwe qwe",
            "phone": "88002600",
            "website": "https://nrc.dev",
            "country_id": 1,
            "city_id": 1,
            "created_at": "2019-11-27 14:19:07",
            "updated_at": "2019-11-27 14:19:07"
          },
          "distances": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "name": "Марафон",
              "created_at": "2019-11-27 14:19:07",
              "updated_at": "2019-11-27 14:19:07",
              "pivot": {
                "event_id": 1,
                "distance_id": 1
              }
            },
            {
              "id": 2,
              "name": "Полумарафон",
              "created_at": "2019-11-27 14:19:07",
              "updated_at": "2019-11-27 14:19:07",
              "pivot": {
                "event_id": 1,
                "distance_id": 2
              }
            }
          ],
          "when": "2020-03-22",
          "start": "11:00:00",
          "active": 1,
          "bookable": 1
        }
      ],
      "links": {
        "first": "http://localhost:3000/events?page=1",
        "last": "http://localhost:3000/events?page=1",
        "prev": null,
        "next": null
      },
      "meta": {
        "current_page": 1,
        "from": 1,
        "last_page": 1,
        "path": "http://localhost:3000/events",
        "per_page": 2,
        "to": 1,
        "total": 1
      }
}
```

Comment: вы думаете, что в строку запроса можно любую шляпу написать, и она работать сама по себе начнет?

Comment: @teran нет просто если без внешнего массива data то такое написание работать будет http://localhost:3000/events?id=1 оно покажет только первый ивент, но мне нужно было обернуть все это дело в массив, и теперь я не знаю как нужно обраться когда используется массив

Comment: @teran и всю эту шляпу что я писал, я находил в просторах инета но оно не работает

Comment: ничего не работает само по себе. надо открыть код и смотреть/изменять его. Если доступа к коду нет, надо открыть документацию и читать ее. Нельзя просто так приписать что-то к строке запроса и надеяться что в выдаче json, что-то поменяется. Каждый запрос обрабатывается неким кодом, который принимает некоторые параметры, и работает с соответствующей логикой. Без знания подробностей реализации вы ничего не сделаете. Не ясно также для чего вам помещать это в массив, особенно на стороне этого апи, поместите в массив на своей стороне.

Comment: @teran даже если я помещу это на своей стороне в апи есть внутренние массивы объектов к которым тоже через запрос нужно будет обратится, без массива все просто ?ключ=значение, а если есть внутренний массив или объект то как к такому обратится через запрос?

Comment: @teran хотя если внутренний объект то его тоже просто получить localhost:3000/events?type.id=1 и все работает, а вот с массивами не понимаю как делать правильно запрос

Comment: вы понимаете, что это не браузер вам фильтрует данные, а код на сервере принимает параметр, и выдает нужные данные?